# Extract value if first characters match text in a range of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with the following formula:

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT(-- (LEFT(A1:D1,5) = "__FTC")),"Exists", "No Exist")`

It successfully detects if the first 5 characters contain the word "__FTC" as shown on column E.

[image]

**I need to get the value instead of just detecting if the value exists as shown below:**

[image]

Comment: If you have access to MS365 then with `XLOOKUP()` works as well, `=XLOOKUP("_FTC*",A1:D1,A1:D1,"",2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A1:D1,MATCH("__FTC*",A1:D1,0)),"")
```

[image]